# Maximal ideals of the ring $\mathbb C \{T\}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables, banach-algebras, rings-of-functions

Consider the Banach $\mathbb C$-algebra
$$
\mathbb C \{T\} = \left\lbrace \sum_{i \geq 0} a_i T^i : \sum_{i \geq 0} |a_i| < \infty \right\rbrace
$$
With the norm given by $\| \sum a_i T^i\| = \sum |a_i|$. By the Gelfand-Mazur theorem, the maximal ideals of this ring is in correspondence with the set of multiplicative functionals $\chi : \mathbb C \{T\} \to \mathbb C$. It is not hard to see that such a functional must be given by
$$
\chi \left(\sum_{i \geq 0} a_i T^i \right)= \sum_{i \geq 0} a_i z^i
$$
for some $z$ with $|z| \leq 1$, so $\operatorname{Max} \mathbb C \{T\} = \overline{D(0,1)}$.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to see the last claim using a combination of commutative algebra and complex analysis, without directly invoking the Gelfand correspondence?
2. Is there a source where algebraic properties of this sort of rings are studied? Like, a description of the prime ideals of $\mathbb C \{T_1, \ldots , T_n\}$, its Krull dimension etc. similar to the study of the local analytic rings $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n}$. I came across this question while learning Berkovich spaces, where Banach rings of the form $k \{T_1, \ldots, T_n\}$ are studied, but the theory there seems to depend heavily on the fact that $k$ is non-Archimedean.

EDITS:

1. (After @YCor's comment) Bad wording of the consequence of Gelfand-Mazur
2. (After @Yemon Choi's comments) Removed the part about $\mathbb C\{T\}$ being a PID and phrased better the question.

Comment: Ostrowski's theorem, i.e. Theorem 5.11 of [Condensed Mathematics and Complex Geometry](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/Complex.pdf), might help.

Comment: I'm confused by the vague conditional "the maximal ideals of this ring *should* be in correspondence". If I understand correctly, they are in correspondence, and more precisely every maximal ideal ***is*** the kernel of a multiplicative functional.

Comment: The algebra you have defined is sometimes known as the *analytic (part of the) Wiener algebra* and it is indeed correct that the maximal ideal spectrum is homeomorphic to the closed unit disc. I'm not sure what you mean in Q1 by seeking a proof using commutative algebra and complex analysis, and your (reasonable) guess about this algebra being a PID is actually incorrect - the kernel of the homomorphism "send T to 1" turns out to be non-principal, IIRC

Comment: @Z.M I am sorry to be one of those grumpy functional analysts (who condensed maths is supposed to put out of business) but what on earth does Ostrowski's theorem have to do with the OP's example or the OP's questions? Might it not be a good idea to learn some Gelfand theory of CBAs before assuming that The Way Of The Condensed will answer all questions?

Comment: Leaving a comment as I don't have time right now to look up the necessary references for a proper answer: your Q2 is natural but it turns out that the ideal theory of CBAs is not as nice as one might think from studying polynomial rings or coordinate rings of varieties. For instance, every infinite-dimensional CBA is non-Noetherian (this is an old result of Sinclair and Tullo) and as I mentioned in my previous comment, Krull dimension is not going to give the right answer unless one ignores "ideals given by points on the boundary"

Comment: @YemonChoi Maybe I misunderstood something, but the OP made it clear in Q1 that they want to avoid Gelfand theory, and in Q2, they said that they want somehow to compare with Berkovich spectra and non-archimedean geometry. Ostrowski's theorem is precisely in this direction: one could prove it by Gelfand theory, but there is a completely elementary proof (without condensed math), and in these notes, the ring of overconvergent functions is analyzed by Ostrowski's theorem (OP's example is the ring of convergent functions).

Comment: Thank you @YemonChoi for your replies and Z. M for the reference. I see that the kernel of evaluation at 1 is not principal. I guess it's also non-finitely generated but don't know how to show that yet. What I mean in Question 1 is something like giving a more or less algebraic property of the ring $\mathbb C \{T\}$ that implies that those are its maximal ideals, without invoking the correspondence with characters. This is inspired in how Rudin shows that $\mathcal O (U)$ is  PID for an open $U \subset \mathbb C$ using theorem 15.13 in his book Real and Complex Analysis

Comment: Thanks Aitor and @Z.M for clarifiying what you meant. Regarding the result that Z.M. links to: the proof they give there looks very similar to me to the "elementary proofs of Gelfand-Mazur without explicitly using Liouville" that can be found in some older books on Banach algebras (Rickart, perhaps, or Zelazko). I notice that this argument has an appeal to continuity, so I don't really think of this as "avoiding the Gelfand correspondence or the GM theorem" so much as repackaging some of the ingredients in a streamlined way

Comment: Aitor: regarding your most recent comment, I had a quick look at the results in Rudin, but I'm not sure how these are supposed to imply that the max ideals in ${\mathcal O}(U)$ correspond to points of $U$. In any case, just so I can try to understand your Q1: are you OK with starting from the argument that kernels of point evaluations are maximal ideals, and are you seeking some argument that all maximal ideals arise this way which does not use G-M?

Comment: @YemonChoi yes, your last statement is correct. I didn't mean that Rudin's book implied anything, I was just talking about the "spirit" if that even makes any sense.

Answer (score 5):

My subjective (but, I think, not un-informed) opinion on Q1 is that one needs norm estimates if one wants to bypass Gelfand-Mazur: informally, I think of this as meaning that Fourier analysis is needed on the boundary circle, not just complex analysis on the interior of the disc. Here is one way this might be achievable — I have not worked through all the details.

I am going to denote your algebra by $W_+$ in my answer.

Let's assume that we are happy with saying that there is a natural inclusion of sets $\overline{\mathbb D} \to {\rm MaxSpec} W_+$, which sends $\lambda$ to the kernel of the evaluation map ${\rm ev}_\lambda: T\mapsto\lambda$. We would like to say that this function is surjective, i.e. that if $f\in W_+$ and ${\rm ev}_\lambda f \neq 0$ for all $\lambda\in \overline{\mathbb D}$ then $f$ lies outside every maximal ideal, equivalently $f$ is a unit in $W_+$.

As you implicitly remarked in the question and your comments, we are fine on the interior of the disc: if $f$ is holomorphic and nowhere vanishing on the open unit disc, then the same is true for $1/f$, so the only issue is whether the Taylor coefficients satisfy the "absolutely summable" condition.

Here comes a philosophical digression: if you imagine the analogous algebra $W$ in which we allow doubly infinite power series in the variable $T$, then this is the so-called Wiener algebra, and we are looking for a proof that if $f\in W$ and ${\rm ev}_\lambda f \neq 0$ for each $\lambda$ on the unit circle then $f$ is a unit in $W$. This was originally (a discrete version of) a theorem of Wiener, but the proof required Fourier-analytic estimates --- and one of the reasons why Gelfand introduced "Gelfand theory " was precisely to say that using characters and the G-M theorem one obtains a much shorter proof!

In other words, somehow your Q1 is the reverse of what Gelfand theory was invented to do.

Having said that: because there are direct proofs that a function $f$ on the unit circle which is nowhere vanishing and has absolutely summable Fourier series has the property that $1/f$ also has absolutely summable Fourier series, one should be able to take one of these proofs and apply it with the extra condition that $f$ is holomorphic on ${\mathbb D}$, to deduce that $1/f$ satisfies the right norm estimates to be in $W_+$. I have seen a fairly hands-on proof written by the non-internet-famous E. B. Davies, which used to be on his webpage before he retired; I think there is also a proof using similar ideas written by the very-internet-famous T. Tao, but I don't recall exactly which blogpost.

My thoughts on Q2 are more pessimistic, I will try to write more when I get some spare time. To get some idea why I think the closed ideal structure of $W_+$ is worse than you (probably) are hoping for, see workof Esterle--Strouse--Zouakia: [Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (1994)](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0803.46052) and [J. Reine Angew. Math. (1994)](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0791.46027)